# Unable to convert textbox(dd/MM/yyyy) date to datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a database date "2014-11-26". I have a calender with format(dd-MM-yyyy) I am trying to bring some values to my form from databse by textbox selected date

```
  protected void txtdate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //DateTime timeIn = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text);
       // DateTime time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        str = "select TimeIn,TimeOut from MusterRoll where EmpCode='" + ddcode.SelectedItem.Text + "' and Date='"+time1+"'";
        dr = conn.query(str);
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            DateTime time = dr.GetDateTime(0);
            TimeSelector1.SetTime(time.Hour, time.Minute, TimeSelector1.AmPm);
            DateTime time2 = dr.GetDateTime(1);
            TimeSelector2.SetTime(time2.Hour, time2.Minute, TimeSelector2.AmPm);
        }

    }
```

The problem is databse date format and my calender format is different. I tried two methods(which I placed in command line)but shows error message like `"input string was not in correct format"`. I surfed internet and find these same answers. May I know why it shows error?? i am trying to make database dateformat and calender format as same

Comment: How are you setting it to the textbox? Please post the code

Comment: Add a `DateTime` parameter to your query and set its value based on the actual DateTime rather than concatenating a string representation of your date time to the query string.

Comment: On which line exactly you get this error? What is your `CurrentCulture`? Are you sure your `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` columns are datetime typed? And why you save your dates as a charater? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @Soner Gönül, see the commanded lines..I tried both but both shows error. There I tried to make my database date format and textbox date format same..

Comment: @BrunoBlane What is `txtdate.Text` exactly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: @Soner Gönül, txtdate.text="26-11-2014"

Comment: @Soner Gönül, this txtdate value I have to convert to yyyyy-mm-dd format then only I get the correct output from database but I cant convert this...shows error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) doesn't have *any* implicit format. It has just date and time values. `String` representations of them can have a format.

I strongly suspect you save your `DateTime` values with their string representations which is a horrible idea. Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) Pass your `DateTime` values directly to your parameterized queries instead of their string representations. Anyway..

For;

```
DateTime timeIn = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text);
```

[`Convert.ToDateTime(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings. That means if your string isn't a standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture` your code throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.formatexception.aspx). I guess `dd-MM-yyyy` is not a standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture`.

For;

```
DateTime time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When you use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx), your string and format should match exactly.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
> DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
> match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown**.

In your case; they are not (`"26-11-2014"` and `"yyyy-MM-dd"`). Use `dd-MM-yyyy` format instead.

```
DateTime time1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate.Text,
                                     "dd-MM-yyyy",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can generate the format from your `time1` like;

```
time1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // A string formatted as 2014-11-26
```

For your command part, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Oh my god..how I explain this."yyyy-MM-dd" format is my database date's format. I want to convert textbox(26-11-2014) to this database format. Then only I can retrive value. Thats why i wrote like that

Comment: @BrunoBlane You saving these dates as `datetime` or related types in your database, right? If so, when you get your `DateTime` from your database, you can format it like `time1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Or just use a parametrized query with the DateTime instance, and not bother with formatting errors in the inline SQL to begin with. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Exactly. He can pass as `Date = @date` and then add it `time1` as a parameter directly **if** (and hope) `Date` column is typed `datetime` or related datetime type :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var dateAndTime=Convert.ToDateTime(Txttradedate.Text).ToString("ddmmyyyy");
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.